# what to do with the tab on the voltage regulator

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator

I want to use the Lt3080 voltage(SOT223) There is also an tab on the voltage regulator. I found it is the same is Vout pin. I am thinking of using the pin to connect it to something else.

But what do i need to do with the Tab pin? 
Ground it? Connect with Vout pin? nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 2 [of the datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3080fc.pdf) tells you.

[image: Tab is out]

"Tab is out"

---

Connect the tab to a large copper area or heat-sink for cooling. The tab is electrically connected to the output within the package, so make sure on your board it is not connected to anything other than the regulator output.

See page 14 for further details.

Comment: oke so if i understand it right. The tab is already connected to the out(pin 2). I only need to create a copper area for the tab and don't connect it to anything further. Is this right?

Comment: @soepblik correct. Though there is no harm in connecting the copper area for the tab to the out pin as well. It may make routing easier as you can bring the trace from the out pin directly under the IC through the tab.

Comment: The heat must **FLOW** away from the tab, thus must flow away from that large copper area. An underlying GND plane, or VDD plane, with bolt-nut contact to move heat to the chassis, must be part of your mechanical planning.

Answer (score 2):

> But what do i need to do with the Tab pin? Ground it? Connect with Vout pin? nothing?

Do not ground it. This is the output of your voltage regulator—connecting this ground, creates a short between your regulated voltage and the gnd.

It may be left floating (Or do what Tom's saying in his answer—it has more to do with heat dissipation than anything else). The (2) pin and tab are electrically connected.